# What configuration must be included in a Kickstart file so packages are pulled from epel, remi, and other remote repositories?

Tags: centos, rhel, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I'm creating kickstart files for various unattended Redhat installs, but for sake of focus, let's say CentOS 7.

I'm using the minimal boot iso, and as part of the boot options, I have `inst.ks=https://gitlab.com/myrepoinfo/-/raw/main/centos7.cfg inst.text ip=dhcp` This works, so DNS is resolving, and the installation succeeds with the exception of detecting and installing packages from remote sources.

[Per the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax), I'm using the `repo` option with the following entries:

```
# Setup additional EPEL and Remi repositories 
repo --name=epel --baseurl=http://ftp.cse.buffalo.edu/pub/epel --install
repo --name=remi --baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm --install
```

Of course these aren't correct, and I get the error that every package under '%packages' cannot be found and would I like to continue anyway (y/n).

So that I can copy and paste from your answer, what are the exact lines of config that I need to add to a kickstart file to allow HTTP based installation of packages from remote sources?

Answer (score 1):

> `repo --name=epel --baseurl=http://ftp.cse.buffalo.edu/pub/epel --install`

This is incorrect because it doesn't point to the root of a repository: you're looking for the directory that contains the `repodata` directory; the directory path will typically include the distribution version and architecture. For the EPEL repository, this would be:

```
repo --name=epel --baseurl=http://ftp.cse.buffalo.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/ --install
```

> `repo --name=remi --baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm --install`

This won't work because you're pointing at a *file*, rather than the root of a package repository. Much like the earlier URL, you want:

```
repo --name=remi --baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/remi/x86_64/ --install
```

I was able to successfully install a centos 7 system with the following kickstart configuration:

```
install
url --url http://mirrors.seas.harvard.edu/centos/7/os/x86_64/

repo --name=epel --baseurl=http://ftp.cse.buffalo.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/ --install
repo --name=remi --baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/remi/x86_64/ --install

text
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
lang en-US.UTF-8
network --bootproto=dhcp --ipv6=auto --activate
firewall --enabled --service=ssh
timezone US/Eastern --isUtc
selinux --enforcing
bootloader --location=mbr
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart
reboot --eject

rootpw --plaintext centos

%packages
@Core
chrony
git
iptables-services
man2html
php82
%end

%post
mkdir -m 700 /root/.ssh
curl -o /root/.ssh/authorized_keys https://github.com/YOURUSERNAME.keys
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

yum -y upgrade
%end
```

And when the install is complete, because of the `--install` argument on the `repo` lines we have:

```
# ls  -l /etc/yum.repos.d | grep -v CentOS
total 48
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   81 Nov  6 14:50 epel.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   86 Nov  6 14:50 remi.repo
```

Comment: You probably also need "remi-safe", and also "remi-php82" if you want PHP 8.2 as a single version (and "remi" is not mandatory). see the wizard instructions https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Also note that EL-7 is now terribly old, especially for modern software such as php 8.2, I heartily recommend a modern version (EL-8 or EL-9). EL-7 will reach its end of life in 20 months